# How to set environment for publishing an ASP.NET Core application

Tags: c#, asp.net, environment-variables

My Environment is still Production

I tried adding `/p:EnvironmentName=Staging` to `dotnet publish -c Release-r win-x64`  but in `seq`, I still see that Environment is Production. How to fix it?
[image]

Comment: read this https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/environments?view=aspnetcore-7.0

Comment: I am in the same boat. @gepa it does not help. What does `For Linux distributions, use the export command at a command prompt for session-based variable settings and the bash_profile file for machine-level environment settings.` mean?

Comment: @EgoPingvina That's just describing how to set environment variables in Linux. If you don't know what environment variables are and how to work with them, then go research that.